# problems with some characters in $_POST['password'];

Tags: php

I have problems with some characters in password input form

`" = \"`

`' = \'`

`\ = \\`

`& = empty`

`+ = empty`

so if user types 
`n1N'11`

in output he will get
`n1N\\\'11`

1) what I am doing wrong? In ajax-php password validation file I use simply `$password=$_POST['password'];` and get such result. In file that records data in mysql, I use `$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);`. But these problems are already at password validation...

2) How to change? I can change \" back to ", but can not change empty to & or +, because do not know what the visitor typed. Or simply not to allow to enter & and +

3) are there some more characters like mentioned?

I am new to programming. Possibly the questions are stupid.

sorry, here is ajax code. but seems i have solved my problem. Need to use encodeURIComponent before pass

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Pasword validation
//pass data without page refresh
function ValidatePassword(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
var hr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "_validator.php";
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

var vars_pass = "&password="+encodeURIComponent(pass);

hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
var return_data = hr.responseText;
document.getElementById("CheckPassword").innerHTML = return_data;

}
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars_pass); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("CheckPassword").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you posting the AJAX request? Can we see that code?

Comment: output where? does your php install have magic_quotes turned on?

Comment: off topic, but just a comment re passwords and good security practices: a password string should never ever be passed to the database without being hashed first. Do not store a password in the DB without hashing it, and do not pass it to the DB to validate without also hashing it. Compare the hashes, not the passwords.

Comment: regarding password hashing... this ajax (onchange) only checks if user typed at least 6 characters (at least one uppercase and lowercase etc.). If user click on Submit, other php code recheck everthing. If all ok, hashes and records in mysql. Is such method safe? Or someone (hacker) can get plain password through ajax? Aim of ajax is simply to help user to enter password. Instead of pressing Submit, user see warning on Javascript OnChange

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the value you pass with javascript in encodeURIComponent(). That way it should preserve the values correctly.